# BLE continuous RSSI scanning with a constant small time interval for android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm making an android application that should scan Bluetooth Low-energy devices RSSIs continuously. I'm using the Google API and my Android version is 4.3. I use Samsung Galaxy S3 for the smartphone, and I'm trying to scan tōd Smart Beacon: https://www.todhq.com/ .

The problem is, that I'm getting values in series like this:

1. Rabidly get 8 RSSI values from the beacon, with approximately 0.4 seconds distance to each.
2. Then there is a big pause (5-6 seconds), when nothing happens.
3. Then again I get 7-8 RSSI values from the beacon...
4. and the big pause again...

and so on.

What I would want to get is continuous intervals between each RSSI value. They don't have to be exact intervals, but at least something near. I have tried with different examples and don't really know what is the problem. Maybe the tod smart beacon only advertises between 5 seconds? And I could somehow change by updating firmware to it the interval of advertising. But then it doesn't make sense that it gets many values between very short intervals, and the values are different (= they are not copies of each).

The code I have been using is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private static final String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private int scanCount;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT=123456;

    // Stops scanning after 1000 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 1000000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            checkBLE();
            init();
            boolean ret = enableBLE();
            if(ret){
                    startScan(false);
            }else{
                    Log.d(TAG,getCtx()+" onCreate Waiting for on onActivityResult");
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
    }

    private void init(){
            // Initializes Bluetooth adapter.
            final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    }
    private void startScan(boolean success){
            if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
                    init();
            }
            if(success){
                    mScanning=true;
                    scanLeDevice(mScanning);
                    return;
            }
            if(enableBLE()){
                    mScanning=true;
                    scanLeDevice(mScanning);
            }else{
                    Log.d(TAG,getCtx()+" startScan Waiting for on onActivityResult success:"+success);
            }
    }
    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
            if (enable) {
                    // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                    mScanning = false;
                                    Log.d(TAG,getCtx() + "run stopLeScan");
                                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                            }
                    }, SCAN_PERIOD);
                    Log.d(TAG,getCtx()+" scanLeDevice startLeScan:"+enable);
                    mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                    Log.d(TAG,getCtx()+ " scanLeDevice stopLeScan:"+enable);
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            }
    }
    private static String getCtx(){
            Date dt = new Date();
            return dt+ " thread:"+Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }
    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
                    new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi,
                            final byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                    scanCount++;

                                    String msg=getCtx()+
                                                    "\nLeScanCallback.onLeScan stopLeScan run " +scanCount+
                                                    "\nDevice:" +device+
                                                    "\nRssi:" + rssi+
                                                    "\nScanRecord:";
                                    Log.d(TAG,msg);
                                    addItems(msg);
                            }
                    });
            }
    };
    private void addItems(String msg) {
            synchronized(listItems){
                    listItems.add(msg);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }
    public void startScan(View v) {
            startScan(false);
    }
    public void stopScan(View v) {
            mScanning=false;
            scanLeDevice(mScanning);
    }
    public void clear(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,getCtx()+" called clear");
            synchronized(listItems){
                    listItems.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }
    private  void checkBLE(){
            // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device. Then
            // you can selectively disable BLE-related features.
            if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
            }
    }
    private boolean enableBLE(){
            boolean ret=true;
            // Ensures Bluetooth is available on the device and it is enabled. If not,
            // displays a dialog requesting user permission to enable Bluetooth.
            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Log.d(TAG,getCtx()+" enableBLE either mBluetoothAdapter == null or disabled:"+mBluetoothAdapter);
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    ret=false;
            }
            return ret;
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            Log.d(TAG,getCtx()+" onActivityResult requestCode="+requestCode+
                            ", resultCode="+resultCode+", Intent:"+data
                            );
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    startScan(true);
            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is a kind of device called "Bluetooth Sniffer", you can use that to check out if the beacon is sending signals as you expected.